# Magento2 - How to make custom module for customize maintenance mode?

Tags: magento2, php, database, magento2.3, php-7

I want to customize maintenance mode in Magento2.

Magento2 error message will be hide and my custom message will be visible.

If you know anything related to this then share with me.

Answer (score 1):

You can Enable Or disable it by using the command line

```
magento maintenance:enable [--ip=<ip address> ... --ip=<ip address>] | [ip=none]

magento maintenance:disable [--ip=<ip address> ... --ip=<ip address>] | [ip=none]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Old Magento 1 Way

Create a copy of the `pub/errors/local.xml.sample` file and update the skin name within to something unique. I usually use the current theme name, say `bigeyedeers`. So the local.xml file should look something like so

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <skin>bigeyedeers</skin>
    <report>
        <action>print</action>
        <subject>Store Debug Information</subject>
        <email_address></email_address>
        <trash>leave</trash>
        <dir_nesting_level>0</dir_nesting_level>
    </report>
</config>
```

Then copy the `pub/errors/default` folder to what ever skin name you chose in the local.xml

```
cp -r pub/errors/default pub/errors/bigeyedeers
```

Now you can update 503.phtml with your custom maintenance page content

## Server Config (Magento 2 Recommended Way)

The recommended way in Magento 2 is by updating the server config, see the following link for more details.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/maint-mode.html#compman-trouble-maint-nginx

## Through a Magento Module

I haven't tried using a Magento module to change the maintenance page before and would recommend against it. But the logic that handles detecting maintenance mode and throwing the 503 is within `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php:assertMaintenance()`. Overwriting this method and requiring your html file then exiting may work.

Comment: I want to make module. Do you have any solution?

Comment: I haven't tried using a module before, but I've updated my answer to include where you can find the maintenance logic to try overriding.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file call `503.phtml` in the directory `pub/errors/default`

This will then be served to the user everytime there is a 503 error which is maintenance mode.